# How can I refresh just a Partial View in its View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

What Am I doing wrong guys? This is the idea...

Index view

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    @Html.Partial("PartialView", Model)
</div>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult PartialView()
{
    return PartialView("PartialView");
}

[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult POSTPartialView(string param1)
{
    return PartialView("PartialView");
}
```

PartialView has a Form.
The first time I enter in Index, PartialView works, but the second time, after a POST call (coming from the form inside of PartialView), I only got to render the PartialView out of the Index.

So to fix it, I´m doing the next:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult POSTPartialView(string param1)
{
    return View("Index");
}
```

That works. I render all Index again (with my changes, after POST). But I refresh all page so I lost a few CSS Elements (accordion discollapsed for example).

Should I use Ajax for refreshing only the div which contents PartialView?

Thanks Mates.

EDITED:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PartialView", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline", role = "form" }))
{
    <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3">
        <label for="DATA">DATA:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" name="DATA">
    </div> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Get Data</button>
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your form declaration?

Comment: Why that is relevant? A standard one... @André Figueiredo

Comment: Because it can be a normal form, an ajax form.. You aren't giving full information

Comment: I didnt get you yet. The form is a normal one then you can call it by Ajax, through controller,... and so on... Anyway, I edited just in case I´m missing somethig... Thanks @André Figueiredo

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, I read the solution ([Auto Refresh Partial View](https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/1132/auto-refresh-partial-view-in-asp-dot-net-mvc)). I am posting it, hoping clarify the question:

**index.html**

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12" id="divPartial">
    @Html.Partial("PartialView", Model)
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#buttonForm").click(function(e){
    $('#form').submit();
    $('#divPartial').load('/PartialController/PartialView'); 
  });
</script>
```

**PartialController**

```
public ActionResult PartialView()
{
    // DO YOUR STUFF. 
    return PartialView("PartialView", model);
}

[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public EmptyResult POSTPartialView(string param1)
{
    // DO YOUR STUFF AFTER SUBMIT.
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: You can also send parameters to the controller something like this: $('#divPartial').load('/PartialController/PartialView?itemId=2095');

Comment: Thanks @robbpriestley. I didnt try this method... Cheers mate

Answer (score 3):

Partial view is oriented to reuse some parts of the code in differents views but when you submit a form, the entire view is reloaded.

If you dont want to reload yo have to use AJAX for submit the form.

Comment: Thanks. How do I join both? Can you provide me a simple example if you dont mind? @Borja Tur

Comment: You can use ajax request adding plain javascript functions in your view but I recommend to use jquery for this purpose for simplicity. Let me looking for a working example of ajax call in jquery.

Comment: Thanks @Borja Tur. I used Ajax before, but when I´m trying to integrate it with Partial View I´m missing something... If you be please and you can provide me a really basic example I could work from there... Even through my simple example as well (my question code). Cheers Borja!

Comment: Here you have explained a basic example code https://cmatskas.com/update-an-mvc-partial-view-with-ajax/ to only reload the partial view I hope can be usefull now, If not, this afternoon I can write a very basic project in github with a working example and link to you that in this post

Comment: Thanks mate. Well, this link contains until I got. The first time I entered in the Partial, index render correctly. But the second one (after a post call because the Partial has a Form inside) is not working. I can render The index correctly (but loosing my css elements, accordion discollapsed - PARTIAL CONTROLLER POST - return View("index")) or I can render the Partial (without the index.cshtml... - PARTIAL CONTROLLER POST - return PartialView("PartialView"))

Comment: @EliasMP here you have a working example https://github.com/borjatur/TestPartialView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117935/discussion-between-eliasmp-and-borja-tur).

Answer (score 1):

Partial view is for reuse some parts of the code in different. When a page is submit then view is reload if you want to avoid page refreshing, you can  use ajax.

**Code for View**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("ControllerName", "ActionName")',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { data: "yourdata" },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(recData) { alert('Success'); },
    error: function() { alert('A error'); }
});
```

**Code for Controller**

```
public JsonResult ActionName(string yourdata)
{
   return Json(p); \\ where p is you want to return
}
```

Comment: It might be better to return the HTML rendered by the Partial View to the AJAX caller. `public ActionResult ActionName() { var viewModel = new MyViewModel(); return PartialView("_MyParitalView", viewModel); }`. To receive HTML, specify the default `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", dataType: "html"` in your ajax call.